# Why can't I create an instance of Web3?

Tags: web3js

I'm using RunKit to test out very simple code that just imports web3 and creates an instance of it. For some reason I get an error saying:

> Cannot find module 'bignumber.js'

[This](https://runkit.com/embed/1oymz4btqwih) is the code.

If you're wondering why I'm using RunKit, it's because I keep getting a bunch of errors when trying to install web3 on my machine so I thought I'd use RunKit just to play around with Web3.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like runkit doesn't support web3js module. Besides, I've tried many related but the same error is fired. If you run just `require("web3")` you will get the same error (check below : Module note found).
 i think you need to discuss this issue on their official [forum](https://discuss.runkit.com/).

[image]

Comment: How are people using it then? If just the require gives an error?

Comment: it's an internal issue, even if you require the missing module : var Web3 = require("bignumber")
the same issue remains. i think you need to discuss this issue on their dedicated forum.